# "Unable to read font " ImageMagick++

Tags: c++, imagemagick

i try this little bit a of code :

```
try {
        InitializeMagick(*argv);
        //create a base image
        Image image("400x100",font_color);

        //construct a drawing list
        std::list<Magick::Drawable> drawList;

        //add tracing elements
        drawList.push_back(DrawableRectangle(0,0,400,100)); // Draw a rectangle ( the sign)
        drawList.push_back(DrawableStrokeColor("black")); // Outline Color
        drawList.push_back(DrawableFillColor(font_color)); // Fill color
        drawList.push_back(DrawableStrokeWidth(5)); 

        drawList.push_back(DrawablePointSize(50));
        drawList.push_back(DrawableFont("@Arial"));
        drawList.push_back(DrawableStrokeColor(police_color)); 
        drawList.push_back(DrawableText(10,70,ville));
        drawList.push_back(DrawableText(300,70,distance));

        image.draw(drawList);
        image.write(filedest);
    }
    catch(exception & error_)
    {
        cout<<"Caught exception : " << error_.what() << endl;
    }
```

but i get this error when i start the program :

proto.exe:unable to read font `@Arial' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1126

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the `@` sign in the font name. It's not needed for the `Magick::DrawableFont` method.

```cpp
drawList.push_back(DrawableFont("Arial"));
```

You can verify the fonts available by running the `identify` utility.

```sh
identify -list font | more
```